# File upload issue in multer.

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm using **multer** for upload a file in node. I have create a API for that and which is works fine with postman. When android developers call my API then I got file as in image.

I cann't understand the issue. Either it is from android side or from my side ?

[image: Image of file in console]

Comment: What do you mean by - You get file as in image?

Comment: Mean I console the req.file and I for file in terminal as you can see in image

Comment: check that the file format/src that is being sent is in the correct format

Comment: @seyi you mean check from android side ?

Comment: yes.Check the file format in which they are sending the file

Comment: They pass data in multi part

Comment: Try checking the file format thats being sent to the server/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the common mistake by developer to pass **header**

**Try to pass this header**

```
'Content-Type':'application/json'
```